Migrating vue2 to vue3 with rollup not able to read html in template file
I did the migration from vue2 to vue3, where vue2 was using rollup. I have updated all the packages with latest version and after that when I trying to start the app its not able to read the html inside the template files, It gives error.
!] (plugin commonjs--resolver) SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:0)
<div>
   ^
3:   <transition name="fade" appear>

This is my rollup.config.js file
import vue from "rollup-plugin-vue";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import image from "@rollup/plugin-image";
import url from "@rollup/plugin-url";
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

var pjson = require("./package.json");

export default {
  input: "src/index.js",
  external: ["vue"],
  output: [
    {
      format: "esm",
      file: "dist/file.js",
      exports: "auto",
      banner: "/**/",
      footer:""
       
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
 
    peerDepsExternal(),
    commonjs(),
    vue({
      template: {
        isProduction: true,
        compilerOptions: {
          whitespace: "condense",
        },
      },
      data: {
        scss: () => `@use 'sass:math'; @import './src/css/index.scss';`,
      },
      compileTemplate: false,
      css: true,
    }),
    copy({
      targets: [
        { src: "src/css/index.scss", dest: "dist/" },
        { src: "src/img/*", dest: "img/" },
        { src: "src/config/*.json", dest: "dist/lang/", rename: (name, extension, fullPath) => `ui_${name}.${extension}` },
        {
          src: "src/config/lang/*",
          dest: "dist/lang",
          rename: (name, extension, fullPath) => `global_${name}.${extension}`
        }
      ],
    }),
    image(),
    url({
      // by default, rollup-plugin-url will not handle font files
      include: [
        "**/*.svg",
        "**/*.png",
        "**/*.jpg",
        "**/*.gif",
        "**/*.woff",
        "**/*.woff2",
      ],
      // setting infinite limit will ensure that the files
      // are always bundled with the code, not copied to /dist
      publicPath: "/public",
    }),
  ],
};

and this the package.json file deps
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-image": "^2.1.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-url": "^8.0.2",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.4.27",
    "btoa": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "rollup": "^2.79.1",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.5.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-vue": "^6.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "vue-styleguidist": "^4.72.4"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-buble": "^1.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@vue/compat": "^3.4.27",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-sass": "^1.12.22",
    "rollup-plugin-scss": "^4.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^14.2.1",
    "sass-math": "^1.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.4.27",
    "vue-columns-resizable": "^0.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^17.4.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3"
}

